# nearby objects within a polygon with Tile 38

Tags: tile38

I have been attempting to do a query where I am searching within a polygon for the closest N number of objects to a specific point.

Currently, i have to do a within, and extend the search limit to a super high number, then run a custom functioning to find nearby, however this takes quite a long time.

Example:  I have a polygon (triangle), and i'm looking for all objects closest to a point on the inside of that triangle.

Thoughts on this? thanks in advance!